# Unable to load background image in Next.JS

Tags: css, next.js

I am new to next.js as I am trying to create website using nextjs I want to add background image on home page but its showing error.I am trying to add image in css style I have image available inside `public` folder below is my code:

**index.js**

```
const Home = () => {
  return(
   <div>
    <section class="sec1">
      <h1>Home page</h1>
    </section>
   </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

**globals.css**

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px; 
}

.sec1{
  background-image: url("../public/banner-food.jpg");
}
```

Someone let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you try ```"url('~/public/baner-food.jpg)"``` this is what I am using to get images into next.js css

Comment: You can simply reference it as `url("/banner-food.jpg")`.